# 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'arrayToDataTable' of undefined or null reference google

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to Jquery,I'm trying to get the google charts..My code is given below and I have an Exception of

> '0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property
>   'arrayToDataTable' of undefined or null reference google'.

```
var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable();
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: your `google.visualization` is null

Comment: `google` might be as well. see if the dependent library is correctly loaded.